# Powershell - problem using $_ ($PSItem) inside a pipe using is own $_

Tags: powershell

I have this script :

```
$cont = @(
    "2019-01-01 00:00:00;0;1;224.94999999999999;13.710000000000001;7.9226000000000005E-2",
    "2019-01-01 00:00:00;0;2;-5.9999999999999998E-2;13.630000000000001;6.0484000000000003E-2"
)
$cont | % {
    $lig = $_ # line for production
    $lig = $cont[0].split(";") # line for test
    $var1 = $lig.split(";")
    try {
        $var1[0].ToDateTime($psitem) 
        $var1[1].ToInt16($_) 
        $var1[2].ToInt16($_)
        $var1[3].ToSingle($_)
        $var1[4].ToSingle($_)
        $var1[5].ToSingle($_) 
    }
    catch {
        write-host "Erreur dans la ligne $lig"
    }

}
```

If I manually run only from the "line for test" to don't use the loop `%`
i have the attempt result:

> mardi 1 janvier 2019 00:00:00 0 1
>   224.95
>   13.71
>   0.079226

but if i Run the entire script (I comment the "line for test"), i have

> Erreur dans la ligne 2019-01-01 00:00:00;0;1;224.94999999999999;13.710000000000001;7.9226000000000005E-2
>   Erreur dans la ligne 2019-01-01 00:00:00;0;2;-5.9999999999999998E-2;13.630000000000001;6.0484000000000003E-2

$Error[0] give me :

> $error[0] Impossible de convertir l'argument «provider» (valeur «2019-01-01 00:00:00;0;2;-5.9999999999999998E-2;13.630000000000001;6.0484000000000003E-2») de «ToDateTime» en type «System.IFormatProvider»: «Impossible de convertir la valeur «2019-01-01  00:00:00;0;2;-5.9999999999999998E-2;13.630000000000001;6.0484000000000003E-2» du type «System.String» en type «System.IFormatProvider».»

it seems like he's confusing the two values `$_` used by `foreach` and `$_` used in `ToInt16($_),ToDateTime($psitem) ...`

How can I do to use the `$var[1].toint16[$_]` method with `$_` who is the value of `$var1[1]` and not the value of `$cont`

Thank you for our help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the foreach() instead of %

```
$cont = @(
    "2019-01-01 00:00:00;0;1;224.94999999999999;13.710000000000001;7.9226000000000005E-2",
    "2019-01-01 00:00:00;0;2;-5.9999999999999998E-2;13.630000000000001;6.0484000000000003E-2"
)
foreach($lig in $cont) {
    # $lig = $_ # line for production
    $lig = $cont[0].split(";") # line for test
    $var1 = $lig.split(";")
    try {
        $var1[0].ToDateTime($psitem) 
        $var1[1].ToInt16($_) 
        $var1[2].ToInt16($_)
        $var1[3].ToSingle($_)
        $var1[4].ToSingle($_)
        $var1[5].ToSingle($_) 
    }
    catch {
        write-host "Erreur dans la ligne $lig"
    }
}
```

I have always had issues with `$_` in a `%` loop when i have other places that generate another variable `$_`. Instead of using `% |`, I would recommend using `foreach($member in $list)` approach.

Comment: This works because $_ and $psitem end up being $null.

Comment: Jawad, thank you for your response. I presume that there are other situation where this occur too.

Comment: js2010, Sorry but I don't speak English well enough to fully understand the subtleties of your answer :-(

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your question.  Something like todatetime() needs an iformatprovider argument https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=netcore-3.1#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_ , but a $null will work.  Or a [Cultureinfo] object.  Without the try/catch, there's plenty of error messages to describe it.  Same idea with toint16() and tosingle().  I don't understand where you think "$_" and "$psitem" should come from.

```
'2019-01-01 00:00:00'.todatetime

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
datetime IConvertible.ToDateTime(System.IFormatProvider provider)


'2019-01-01 00:00:00'.todatetime('2019-01-01 00:00:00')

MethodException: Cannot convert argument "provider", with value: "2019-01-01 00:00:00", for "ToDateTime" to type "System.IFormatProvider":
"Cannot convert the "2019-01-01 00:00:00" value of type "System.String" to type "System.IFormatProvider"."


'2019-01-01 00:00:00'.todatetime($null)               

Tuesday, January 1, 2019 12:00:00 AM


'2019-01-01 00:00:00'.todatetime([Cultureinfo]'en-US')

Tuesday, January 1, 2019 12:00:00 AM
```